# How to find newly added, deleted and modified files in git repository

Tags: git, git-svn, egit

Is there a command that would generate a list of every deleted file,added and modified files in the repository.Pls suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare between two branches:

- your current one
- the remote one (that you have fetched)

From the Egit user manual: "[Comparing with Branches (Synchronize)](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.egit.doc/help/EGit/User_Guide/Tasks.html#Comparing_with_Branches_.28Synchronize.29)"

[image: Synchronize dialog]

You can see it in action in the answer "[Eclipse and EGit: How to easily review changes to ALL modified files before committing to *local* repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11259743/6309)".
That answer is written by [Thomas Ferris Nicolaisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266875/thomas-ferris-nicolaisen), who also does the excellent podcat **[gitminutes](http://www.gitminutes.com/)**.

---

For checking your work in progress (like `git status` does), use the **[Egit Staging view](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Git_Staging_View)**.

[image: Git staging view]

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command in your repository once you fetched the branch.

```
git diff --name-only <branch-name> origin/<branch-name>
```

This will compare your local branch and the remote branch and list the file names that has been modified.